# Why are all the numbers print out when I want only the largest?

Tags: java

I want to display only the largest number (price) from a text file. Every time it shows me the whole numbers instead of the highest value. I've been using a lot of methods like the for loop and others. But I think the problem is about something else.

```
 package practice;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;
 public class Practice {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
      String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Work\\Desktop\\Prices.txt";
      File inFile = new File(fileName);
      Scanner inPut = new Scanner(inFile);
      String line = inPut.nextLine();
      while(inPut.hasNext()){


        String[] Company = new String[3];
        int[] Price = new int[3];
        int[] Quality = new int[3];

        int count = 0;
        count++;

        Company[count] = inPut.next();
        Price[count] = inPut.nextInt();
        Quality[count] = inPut.nextInt();


        int HighestPrice = Price[0];

        int counter = 1;
        while(counter<Price.length-1){
          if(Price[counter]>HighestPrice){
              HighestPrice = Price[counter];
              int hi = counter;
            }
            counter++;
          }
          System.out.println(HighestPrice);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you indented your code propely, you would understand the structure it has, and thus understand when the highest price is computed and displayed, and thus where your mistake is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the loop body after taking input in the arrays.
You should create your arrays outside the loop as their reference gets lost each time you recreate them.

```
String line = inPut.nextLine();
String[] Company = new String[3];
int[] Price = new int[3];
int[] Quality = new int[3];
int count = 0;
while(inPut.hasNext()){
  Company[count] = inPut.next();
  Price[count] = inPut.nextInt();
  Quality[count] = inPut.nextInt();
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the code to find the largest number inside the `while(inPut.hasNext()){` Block. because of that the `while(counter<Price.length-1){` loop gets executed on every line and therefore only has one value to handle, which of course is everytime the largest.

Skip the second loop and only execute the code inside, put the `System.out.println(HighestPrice);` outside the outer loop and it should work.